# RevMob crashes when ad closed

Tags: ios, ios5, revmob, revmobads

I have two `UIViewControllers`. On first One i have an `UIButton` which calls the second `viewController`. When I'm on `secondViewController` the RevMob ads shows.

```
[[RevMobAds session] showFullscreen];
```

If i press "x" button on the corner of the add, i mean to Close this add, the app goes to `FirstViewController` and that `UIButton` which calls the `secondViewController` DOESN'T WORK ANYMORE.

This happens on iOS 5 on Simulator and Device. on iOS 6 works great.

Please help me, I contacted `RevMob` but they didn't answer.

Comment: Did you include the -all_load flag on Other Linker Flags under Build Settings?

Comment: Oh. yes... i did it. RevMob guys said that I have to present my ViewController using other ways, not presentModalViewController, because there is a conflict between their SDK and iOS 5

Answer (score 0):

The version 5.9.1 says on the [change log](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios_download.html) that this issue is solved.